# How to show Docker errors in Bamboo?

Tags: windows, docker, bamboo

I'm currently using Docker for Windows with Bamboo. I'm running into the problem, that when a Docker task fails, the error log only shows that exact message, that the task failed. But it doesn't show the error message from within Docker, like compilation errors, access denied or out of memory. Is there any way to get to these error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a task in the "Final tasks" area of your job.  This job will execute regardless of whether the tasks in the job failed or not.

Depending on how you are running Docker in Bamboo you can make this a Docker task or a script task and use the Docker logs command to output the logs from the container.  This should tell you why the container failed to run (e.g., build, run-time error, initialization failure).

[Docker Logs CLI](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already figuered it out though. You can selected the failed job, go to logs, and then to view to see the entire output. Nevertheless this is probably a good method for automization.